# java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-eo/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 2

Tags: java, hadoop

We get an exception again and again when I deploy hadoop namenode on our host, could anyone help to give any advice on it ? Thanks in advance.

```
2014-08-05 09:08:00,538 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of transactions: 31 Total time for transactions(ms): 1Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 21 SyncTimes(ms): 17
2014-08-05 09:08:00,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 189 on 22700, call addBlock(/tmp/hadoop-eo/mapred/system/jobtracker.info, DFSClient_1214769458, null) from 10.80.146.177:46093: error: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-eo/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 2
java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-eo/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 2
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:685)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
2014-08-05 09:08:10,558 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 280 on 22700, call addBlock(/tmp/hadoop-eo/mapred/system/jobtracker.info, DFSClient_1214769458, null) from 10.80.146.177:46094: error: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-eo/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 2
java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-eo/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 2
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:685)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
```

Comment: What is the output of `jps`?

Comment: try the following: stop all hadoop services, delete dfs/name/* and dfs/data/* directories, `hadoop namenode -format` and then start hadoop services again. This will remove all your data!

Comment: @vefthym Yeah,I have tried it several times, and it didn't work.

Comment: @Balduz `./jps
27052 Jps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrolling exception disappeared after datanode set up.
I think it's expected exception if there is no available datanode, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start hadoop services? 
As your jps is showing that only jps is running.

```
$HADOOP_PATH/sbin/start-dfs.sh
$HADOOP_PATH/sbin/start-yarn.sh 
or
$HADOOP_PATH/sbin/start-all.sh
```

If you have started hadoop services and yet facing same error, could you upload hadoop log files?